# Logic behind a booking system?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm really new to Oracle Apex and I'm making a booking app for a hotel for my final project and i cant wrap my head around the Booking process for rooms. Lets say i have 2 tables:

1. table named `ROOMS` that has `ROOM_ID, ROOM_NUMBER,PERSONS_PER_ROOM, ROOM_STATUS, ROOM_DATE` attributes.(`ROOM_STATUS` can only be set to 'FREE' or 'TAKEN'
2. table named `RESERVATIONS` that has `ID_RES, DATE_OF_ARRIVAL, DATE_OF_DEPARTURE, PERSON_NUMBER, ROOM_ID_FK`

Now my train of thought was to set `ROOM_STATUS to 'TAKEN'`and `DATE_OF_DEPARTURE=ROOM_DATE` once the form for `RESERVATIONS` is submitted. Also to make an automation to set `ROOM_STATUS = 'FREE'` once `ROOM_DATE > CURRENT_DATE`  And then if i want to make another reservation for the same `ROOM_ID` but on a later date i could just set a where clause on my LOV in my `RESERVATIONS` form to show only `ROOM_ID`-s where `ROOM_STATUS = 'FREE' OR DATE_OF_ARRIVAL >= ROOM_DATE`. I thought i was smart as hell for that but then i realized that if someone makes a Room reservation from 04.July till 15.July and  another reservation from 15.august to 25.august for the same room i wouldn't be able to make a reservation on that `ROOM_ID` in between 15. July and 15.august.

How do i handle this situation? I looked all over the internet for info on this and yes there are threads on Oracle-s sites and on stack overflow with all kinds of links but none of those links lead to anywhere or the stuff has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about yet another table, a calendar? It would have the following columns:

```
create table reservation_calendar
  (id_cal    number constraint pk_cal primary key,
   datum     date,
   id_res    number constraint fk_cal_res references reservations (id_res)
  );
```

You'd pre-populate it with e.g. one year's dates for all rooms (so, if this year has 365 days and there are 10 rooms, you'd create 365 * 10 = 3650 rows).

Then, when someone makes reservation, you'd `UPDATE` that table and set `ID_RES` column to reservation ID - it'll tell you that room (which can be found via another  foreign key from `reservations` to `rooms` and `room_id_fk` column) is *taken*. If you want to de-normalize the model, that new table could contain the `room_id` (or even room number) column as well; it would make queries simpler, but - I wouldn't do that, if I were you - I'd rather create a *view* that joins all 3 tables.

During reservation process, you'd be able to display room statuses between `date_of_arrival` and `date_of_departure`, day-by-day; guests would then *visually* be able to make up their mind and make a reservation for that, or some other period - but you'd actually *see* what's going on.

---

I don't understand what is `room_date` supposed to represent so I can't follow what you wrote about it, nor I have any comment.

Comment: Thank you so much! This also works! Room_ date was my primitive way of setting ROOM_STATUS back to 'FREE' once a reservation expired. Wasnt very smart i know xD

Comment: You're welcome; good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are going about it the wrong way. What you need to do is

1. get all rooms not present in (reservations table with constraints new arrival/departure dates overlaps with existing reservations)
2. So your query should look something like below

```
SELECT ROOM_ID FROM ROOMS WHERE ROOM_ID NOT IN (
SELECT ROOM_ID_FK FROM RESERVATIONS 
WHERE (DATE_OF_ARRIVAL< {NEWBOOKING_STARTDATE} AND DATE_OF_DEPARTURE>{NEWBOOKING_STARTDATE}) 
OR (DATE_OF_ARRIVAL< {NEWBOOKING_ENDDATE} AND DATE_OF_DEPARTURE>{NEWBOOKING_ENDDATE})
);
```

Please let me know if I have missed some corner case here.
Also Note that DATE_OF_ARRIVAL and DATE_OF_DEPARTURE in the where clause is for existing bookings. Just saying so that there is no confusion.